# Wordpress - в доп. поле не сохраняются числа с дробью

Tags: php, html, sql, wordpress

Есть функция добавления доп. поля в комментарии wordpress:

```
// ПОЛЕ ЦЕНА В КОММЕНТАРИЯХ
// Добавляем поля в форму комментариев

// Добавляем метаданные комментария
add_action('comment_post', function ($comment_id) {
  if (!empty($_POST['price'])) {
    $price = intval($_POST['price']);
    add_comment_meta($comment_id, 'price', $price);
  }
});

// Добавляем новый метабокс на страницу редактирования комментария
add_action('add_meta_boxes_comment', function() {
  add_meta_box('title', __('Доп. информация'), 'extend_comment_meta_box', 'comment', 'normal', 'high');
});

// Отображаем наши поля в админке
function extend_comment_meta_box($comment) {
  $price  = get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'price', true );

  wp_nonce_field('extend_comment_update', 'extend_comment_update', false);
  ?>
  <p>
    <label for="comment-price"><?php _e( 'Цена' ); ?></label>
    <input id="comment-price" type="number" name="price" step='0.01' value="<?php echo esc_attr( $price ); ?>" class="widefat" />
  </p>
  <?php
}

// Редактируем наши поля в админке
add_action('edit_comment', function($comment_id) {
  if (!isset($_POST['extend_comment_update']) || ! wp_verify_nonce($_POST['extend_comment_update'], 'extend_comment_update')) return;

  if(!empty($_POST['price'])) {
    $price = intval($_POST['price']);
    update_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'price', $price );
  }
  else {
    delete_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'price');
  }
});

// Возвращает среднее щначение цены поста
function get_the_extend_comment_post_price() {
  global $wpdb;
  $price = 0;

  if ( is_singular() ) {
    $post_id = (int) get_the_ID();
    $price  = wp_cache_get( $post_id, 'post_avg_price' );

    if ( false === $price ) {

      $price = $wpdb->get_var( "
               SELECT ROUND(AVG(cm.meta_value),2) as avg
                FROM $wpdb->commentmeta as cm
                JOIN $wpdb->comments as c
                ON cm.comment_id = c.comment_ID
                WHERE c.comment_post_ID IN ($post_id) AND cm.meta_key = 'price'
          " );
      $price = $price ?: 0;

      wp_cache_add( $post_id, $price, 'post_avg_price' );
    }


  }

  return $price;
}
```

Почему не сохраняются цифры с дробью - 4,5 и тд?
Подскажите, как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

перед сохранением данных вы используете [intval](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.intval.php) которая приводит значение к целому числу, замените ее на [floatval](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.floatval.php)

```
add_action('comment_post', function ($comment_id) {
  if (!empty($_POST['price'])) {
    $price = floatval($_POST['price']);
    add_comment_meta($comment_id, 'price', $price);
  }
});

add_action('edit_comment', function($comment_id) {
  if (!isset($_POST['extend_comment_update']) || ! wp_verify_nonce($_POST['extend_comment_update'], 'extend_comment_update')) return;

  if(!empty($_POST['price'])) {
    $price = floatval($_POST['price']);
    update_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'price', $price );
  } else {
    delete_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'price');
  }
});
```